# Check users role Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

After a user enters his credential and tries to login and after the user is found, we have a siterole table that will be checked, if the role that the user selected is found in the database "where userID=request and roleType = request" then the login is successful otherwise it fails due to choosing the wrong user role.
The code is simple:

```
$findrole = $request->role;
$user_id = Auth::user()->id;

$userrole =  DB::table('siterole')->where('role_id' ,'=',$findrole)->where('user_id' ,'=', $user_id)->get();
 if(!empty($userrole)) {
 make it login
}
   else{
redirect it with a fail login
  }
```

By failed login I mean no session should be set, where I tried this code was in

```
vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php
```

**BUT** when the "role_id" is not found for that "user_Id", the user is logged in and redirected to the wrong page!
**Edit** the function Im putting my code in is this :
         public function login(Request $request)
    {

```
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    $throttles = $this->isUsingThrottlesLoginsTrait();

    if ($throttles && $lockedOut =         $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);




    if (Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {

      //MYCODE GOES BETWEEN THESE LINES

   if its not empty return the below code      
        return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);

    }

    if ($throttles && ! $lockedOut) {
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
    }

         //if its empty return to this section

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);

}
```

Comment: If you write "dd($userrrole)", what do you see? Maybe you can include this in your question. It looks like that userrolevariable contains some data.

Comment: I deleted my previous answer but try to print the userrole variable using dd.

Comment: dd($userrole) returns either null  or the row that has been selected

Comment: @PcMonk *"dd($userrole) returns either null or the row that has been selected"* - Not if you're using `->get()`; it'll return an empty `Collection` or a `Collection` of 1 row. You're describing the result when using `->first()`. Maybe try using a combination of `->first()` followed by `if(!$userrole)`

Comment: still the same , its like the if doesnt count , and inside it its a return function to loginfailed function which sends us to the failedview , but instead we go right into dashboard, I did a dd on userrole while doing first() INSIDE the if(!$userrole) which was a null value that means user selected the wrong role,it printed it out but the next line which is return->this->sendfail($request) it gets skipped somehow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, so where i was putting my condition is where laravel already returned  a login = true, so i cant do anything.

that **attemp()** is actually attempting the login which is located in :

vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard.php

now in attemp function we dont have access to our request but we can pass the **User type** i call it (role) in function getCredentials which is located in :

vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php
 **Step 1:**

```
protected function getCredentials(Request $request)
{
    //sending role as credential too
      // my input name was role 
    return $request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'password','role');
}
```

Now since we passed it in attemp() , its the 2nd array of our credentials **BUT** we have to unset it from the main credentials because laravel will create a where clause for each key in array :
 **Step 2**

```
  public function attempt(array $credentials = [], $remember = false, $login = true)
   {
     //get the user roll to check if the user has the same role 
    //else kill him #Stormspirit
    $user_role = $credentials['role'];
   //as laravel make the where clause for every field we unset it from the array
   unset($credentials['role']);

    $this->fireAttemptEvent($credentials, $remember, $login);

    $this->lastAttempted = $user = $this->provider->retrieveByCredentials($credentials);

    // If an implementation of UserInterface was returned, we'll ask the provider
    // to validate the user against the given credentials, and if they are in
    // fact valid we'll log the users into the application and return true.
    if ($this->hasValidCredentials($user, $credentials)) {
      //user credential was valid check the role part
        $userrole_finder = DB::table('siterole')->where('role_type',$user_role)->where('user_id',$user->id)->get();

        if($userrole_finder==[]) {

            $login = false;
            return false;
        }
        if ($login) {
            $this->login($user, $remember);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

All set! dont forget to add **use DB;** check your user role table and if it was empty make the login false and return false that would do the rest and u will see laravel's invalid credential error.

You can implement this for user type I just called it role.you can also put the user type in a session in handleUserWasAuthenticated function in AuthenticatesUsers.php , exact location described above

```
 protected function handleUserWasAuthenticated(Request $request, $throttles)
    {
        session(['user_role' => $request->role]);
        if ($throttles) {
            $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
        }

        if (method_exists($this, 'authenticated')) {
            return $this->authenticated($request, Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->user());
        }

        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Auth::user()->id` returns the user id only when you are authenticated. In line 2 of your example code, when you are creating the $user_id variable you are not authenticated yet so it will always be null. You'll need to get the user_id another way.

Comment: did an update on the post , i should mention problem is not the auth and im using a registered user but with different role type: so if he is a admin and he choose superadmin he should come back to the login page, but it login instead